# Gas Estimation on Flow chain

Tags: onflow-cadence

I am using Flow Javascript Library to send Crypto Currency from One Wallet Address to another.

How do I calculate Gas Estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start the emulator with `--transaction-fees` it will use the same gas fee algorithm as testnet/mainnet so then you can run the transaction locally and see the result there first?

If you are only doing a simple send FT the gas/fee will be very small. Here is an example https://flowscan.org/transaction/227b752908136da94f3006b5c14ef31495fc0ca27bae73732d68b8ef879fe23f

This uses **68 gas** and the fee is **0.00000439 flow**

Comment: I am using Flow Javascript SDK; and I want to calculate what is the current GAS Fess on the chain; is there a method to do that.  I don't want to set one fixed Value.

Comment: No there is no such method.